# How to remove an outline from a selected Card Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, focus, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-cards

I have to make a website using the Bootstrap 5 framework, so I've been messing around with "Bootstrap Cards". When I click on a card a border appears. Thought I might fix it overwriting it using the pseudo element :focus

`.card:focus {outline: 0 !important;`

E.g.:

[image]

I guess it's something else then an outline, but don't have the needed knowledge of HTML

Comment: Many Bootstrap elements are using box-shadow for `:focus` states. Try `box-shadow: none`. Have you wrapped it in an `<a>` tag or why is it *focusable*? Because if I try to focus on a card, it is not possible.

Comment: Tried that as well, really don't know why it's focusable, didn't wrap it in an `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Check `.card` class has a `border`

To remove it simply override it to `border: none;`

Comment: that's not what I mean, the border only appears when the Card is selected. Already removed the border tho.

Comment: try to select the pseudo element as well `:active`

Comment: Tried it, but it isn't working. `:active` is mostly used on `a` tags or `button`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
.card:focus {
   border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Also tried it. I found out the problem isn't situated at the Cards, but at the Scrollspy. Take a look here: gip.lukramon.com

Comment: Yup, probably that. I took a look at the code and nothing on card class on the console.
Did you fixed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 has a separate class `border-0` for this.

Try running the code below with and without the `border-0` class to see how it works.

More about borders in Bootstrap [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/borders/).
Hope this helps:)

```html
<!--link to bootstrap 5 script and styles-->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- bootstrap 5 card with no borders without modifying your .css-->
<!--attention to the border-0 class below-->

<div class="card border-0"> 
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1 class="display-1">Card With No Borders!</h1>
    <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elementum dui arcu, eu aliquet odio elementum non. Curabitur vel mi ligula. In vel dolor diam. Curabitur ornare, magna eget ultrices luctus, magna lectus tempus dui, non facilisis elit dolor eu risus. </p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">A Button</a>               
  </div>
</div>
```